# Source for 2-pin barrel-connector extension cable? 12v

Tags: electrical, cables, connectors

My wife bought a couple of Addlon Lighting outdoor LED string lights, which connect via 2-pin barrel-type connector to the power supply.  They can be daisy-chained, so one end is M, other is F, etc.

I want to mount the 12V power supply near a power outlet, but over 10ft away from where I'd like to start the LED light string.  I'm trying to find a source for an extension cable, or find the specs for the connector where I can make my own.

I find all manner of 2-pin 12V extension cables on say, Amazon, but the dimensions of the connector and pin separation vary wildly - searching on the power supply model number yields only references to the Very Large Corporate Entity that engineers devices for other manufacturers.

Here's a pic showing the connector I'm trying to find:
[image: PSU and cable]

And a closeup of the ends of the included extension cable (very short):
[image: 2-pin connectors]

I've tried emailing their support address, but despite showing them the pictures above, they keep insisting that a standard 120V AC extension cord will work.

Has anyone else tried to do this?

Comment: The supplier should have an extension.  However this is off topic

Comment: Is there a reason you can't extend the house current side? Otherwise, try a real electronic supply house.

Comment: Looks like this one https://www.amazon.com/BTF-LIGHTING-Plastics-Waterproof-connctor-Applicable/dp/B01LCV8DXQ?th=1, check whether your connector also has 4.5 mm distance between pins.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is only 12V, I would:

- Chop a cable in half
- Carefully strip a couple of inches of the outer insulation from each cut end
- Hopefully find insulated wires inside that can be connected with wire nuts or Wago connectors
- Splice in some *cordage*. You could use NM cable (Romex) but cordage will be more flexible and, if rated appropriately, better for outside use.
- Wrap it all up well with waterproof electrical tape or something similar. Heat shrink tubing is generally a good way to go, but not really necessary here because it is low voltage.

The good news: With 12V and relatively low current, there really isn't any danger if you mess up.

The bad news: Sometimes you cut into a cord and find that the wires are very thin and hard to work with to splice them.

Comment: If its low voltage, barrel jacks are a standard

Comment: Made in China, sold on Amazon, no UL listing

Comment: @Ruskes Don't know which specific product OP purchased. But a quick search finds, for example, [this one on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/addlon-Outdoor-Dimmable-Commercial-Weatherproof/dp/B07QMKZWQF?th=1) which claims ETL Listing. I have said many times "UL or ETL" - if they are telling the truth about ETL, that solves the problem.

Comment: Absolutely support this answer! A larger bit of color-matched heat-shrink tubing slipped over the cable, then small bits over each individual soldered joint will give a reasonably nice, professional (if done neatly) appearance to the whole thing. Putting the splices where they can be hidden will make it even better looking.